# using variable before it is defined

Tags: vhdl

```
   process is
         variable a_var, b_var : std_logic ?
   begin
         wait until ( rising_edge ( clk ) );

             a_var := x or y ;
             b_var := a_var nor z ;
             res   <= b_var xor y ;

   end process:
```

In this case, IS the variable b_var  used before it has been defined ? If yes, can one explain why .

Comment: This sounds a lot like a homework question.  You should tag this as "homework" if that's the case.

Comment: No, it is not homework. Actually, there is no school. Summer !

Comment: @fatai: My bad.  The question seemed more theoretical to me.  I would expect "used before defined" warnings/errors would be thrown when building the bin file.  (Do you get one?)

Comment: You have syntax errors in your post: put a semicolon at the end off the variable declaration (was question mark "?") and at the end of process (was colon ":"). Please correct them, so that others won't be confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you've quite clearly defined it on the `variable` line. You've also set the value of `b_var` before you use it in the process, which means that no flip-flop will be inferred for it.

Your code is the equivalent of

```
FOO: process(clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        res <= ((x or y) nor z) xor y;
    end if;
end process FOO;
```

(I've overlooked a couple of syntax errors in your code, assuming them to be just typos.)